# Unable to check a checkbox if it has a link in it

Tags: html, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am testing an application and it contains two checkboxes to accept some license agreement, something like:

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="pretty p-default p-smooth p-curve p-thick">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div class="state p-info-o">
      <label>I read the
        <a class="checkbox-link" target="_blank"
          href="link">privacy terms bla bla</a>.
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br >
  <small class="error">You have to accept</small>
</div>
```

The issue comes with [pretty-checkbox](https://github.com/lokesh-coder/pretty-checkbox/issues/78) that hides the real checkbox and adds one using the `a:before` trick. Clicking the item will check the fake box but if you add an anchor on top of it, it will click first the link. I am sure there is a workaround in the CSS so the fake checkbox takes priority.

Comment: This code in itself doesn't show your reported issue. There must be something along. You should add some CSS and/or JS-Code. This should be done in a way to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Yes, that made me think that maybe there were a CSS issue. I will try to see how can I make a reproducible e2e test.